# XML Data Fetch help need

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file for my project work.I need to fetch the data from the XML file.The file contains something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0" xmlns:szgd="http://www.spotzot.com/gdfeed" xmlns:szbb="http://www.spotzot.com/bbfeed">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Service &amp; Maintenance under $50</title>
<description>7 Items | Prestone, Campbell Hausfeld, Custom Accessories, Custom, KD Tools</description>
<szgd:instore>Y</szgd:instore>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I am using `$newtitle=$newxml->channel->item->title;` to fetch data from title.It successfully returned the title.

How can I fetch the data from  tag in my page using php?

Comment: which tag you are asking ?

Comment: How did you load `$newxml`?

Comment: I am just solved it.with $newxml->channel->item->children('http://www.spotzot.com/gdfeed')->instore. Here the link in children() is the value of szgd , which is defined top of the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php's simplexml functions.

Load it with:
`$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);` if you are having a string or
`$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);` if you are having a file.

if the xml was valid you will get a SimpleXmlElement. Check the following link: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php. There you will find several functions on how to get data out of it.

Btw. which data you really want to get?